# NoMethodError: undefined method `save' rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm learning RoR from ruby.railstutorial.org , i have created a model and when im trying to add data to it and save via rails console im getting error. (Im using mysql )

Rails Console

```
 User.new(username: "test", password: "test123", password_confirmation: "test123", email: "test@fs.in", role: "admin" )
 => #<User id: nil, username: "test", password: "test123", email: "test@fs.in", role: "admin", created_at: "2012-01-01 00:00:00", updated_at: "2012-01-01 00:00:00", password_confirmation: "test123">
```

User.save gives below error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for #<Class:0x0000000422b628> from /home/ramadas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
from (irb):15
from /home/ramadas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /home/ramadas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /home/ramadas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

My Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role, :username
  validates :username, presence: true , length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX } , uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }
  before_save { |user| user.username = username.downcase }
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

I have checked for every possible mistake that could happen, but didnt find a solution. please help me out in figuring out and solve this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you calling `User.save` or `User.new(username:...).save`?

The class/model `User` doesn't have a `save` method defined on it, but instances of the class do (coming from `ActiveRecord::Base`).

Try the following:

```
user = User.new(username:...)
user.save
```